# LocationListener, LocationRequest, LocationServices imports invalid while implementing Google Maps API to find nearby places in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-gradle-plugin

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

The above 3 imports are deemed invalid. I have the Google Play Services, Google Support Repository, Google Repository all installed essentially all SDK Tools I need are installed but I don't understand why the 3 above imports work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile the necessary Google Play Services components with the dependencies of your project.

Make sure you have these compile statements in your app level `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
    //.......
}
```